# Adding an inner border with the same distance from each edge of an image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, borders

How can I add a border within an image, like in the example below but preserving constant distance from the edges of that image? Currently I draw a rectangle shape with no fill, I can center it horizontally and vertically, but I don't know how to preserve the same distance on each side. 
Another similar question would be how can I draw an inner border preserving image aspect ratio?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are other ways to achive this, but here's what I can think of:

- select all via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- right click anywhere and choose 'Transform Selection'
- in the toolbar, where you have percentages, right click and choose pixels in both fields (see red dots below)
- do the math and edit those 2 numbers, so if your image is 1000x1000 pixels and you need a 50px border on all sides, type in '900px' in both fields
- create a new layer if you need the border as a separate layer
- use `Edit > Stroke` with a white color and tick the 'Inside' option

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done with a script. Save the code below as a `yourname.jsx` to `%Photoshop Folder%/Presets/Scripts`, restart Photoshop and you'll find it in `File > Scripts > yourname` menu and it will add a border in one click.

There're some settings you can change: stroke width, color, distance...

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by inner border preserving the aspect ratio though.

Result:
[image]

```
var stroke, settings;

settings = {
  side: 20, // border distance in pixels
  strokeOnNewLayer: true, // create a border on a new layer?
  strokeWidth: 4, // width of the stroke
  strokeColor: 'ffffff', // color in HEX format (ffffff is white)
};

stroke = (function()
{

  var doc;

  var controller = function()
  {
    try
    {
      checker();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
      alert(e + '\nLine: ' + e.line);
      return false;
    }

    doc = activeDocument;

    if (settings.strokeOnNewLayer) doc.artLayers.add();

    rectSelection();

    strokeWithColor();

    doc.selection.deselect();

  };

  var rectSelection = function()
  {
    var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref = new ActionReference();
    ref.putProperty(cTID('Chnl'), cTID('fsel'));
    desc.putReference(cTID('null'), ref);
    var descCoords = new ActionDescriptor();
    descCoords.putUnitDouble(cTID('Top '), cTID('#Pxl'), settings.side);
    descCoords.putUnitDouble(cTID('Left'), cTID('#Pxl'), settings.side);
    descCoords.putUnitDouble(cTID('Btom'), cTID('#Pxl'), doc.height.as("px") - settings.side);
    descCoords.putUnitDouble(cTID('Rght'), cTID('#Pxl'), doc.width.as("px") - settings.side);
    desc.putObject(cTID('T   '), cTID('Rctn'), descCoords);
    executeAction(cTID('setd'), desc, DialogModes.NO);
  };

  var strokeWithColor = function()
  {
    var strokeColor = new SolidColor();
    strokeColor.rgb.hexValue = settings.strokeColor;

    var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc.putInteger(cTID('Wdth'), settings.strokeWidth);
    desc.putEnumerated(cTID('Lctn'), cTID('StrL'), cTID('Insd'));
    desc.putUnitDouble(cTID('Opct'), cTID('#Prc'), 100.000000);
    desc.putEnumerated(cTID('Md  '), cTID('BlnM'), cTID('Nrml'));
    var descData = new ActionDescriptor();
    descData.putDouble(cTID('Rd  '), strokeColor.rgb.red);
    descData.putDouble(cTID('Grn '), strokeColor.rgb.green);
    descData.putDouble(cTID('Bl  '), strokeColor.rgb.blue);
    desc.putObject(cTID('Clr '), cTID('RGBC'), descData);
    executeAction(cTID('Strk'), desc, DialogModes.NO);

  }

  var checker = function()
  {
    if (documents.length == 0) throw 'no documents found, aborting';
  };

  var cTID = function(s)
  {
    return app.charIDToTypeID(s);
  };

  var sTID = function(s)
  {
    return app.stringIDToTypeID(s);
  };

  return controller;
})();

app.activeDocument.suspendHistory("create stroke", "stroke()");
```